# How can I add Cyberware?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

How can I add cyberware? I have 6/6 essence, I have the money and the doc sells the cyberware I want.

I tried selecting it and then clicking on "install", but somehow it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to drag it over to the slot on your paper doll on the right side of the screen when you have the cyberware shop open. It can be a little finicky to get it to drop into the slot correctly.

Comment: a little finicky?  it was a damned miracle i managed to add a dataport after 10 tries

Comment: @spartacus I was being generous. Its actually a complete PITA. Honestly I almost gave up trying when I first tried to do it and wasn't 100 percent sure the click and drag method was right

Comment: You don't have to drag. You can click on the cyberware and then on the slot on the paper doll to get it to appear. If you want to upgrade the cyberware, you have to first click the "refresh" symbol off to the right of the item in the left panel, and then on the ware on the doll.

Comment: I think they patched it, now it works way better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click on the `+` symbol on the cyberware description to have it automatically added to a slot on the paper doll, then you can click install.

Answer (score 0):

click the + next to the item then click the highlighted box in your paper doll then click install..